# Why when open xls file generated by PHPExcel then click save the size decreases?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, excel-2003

I use PHPexcel_1.8 to generate Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)

```
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$objWriter->save($myFile);
```

If I open the file and press <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (without making any change), the size drops almost to 50%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.... PHPExcel doesn't waste precious PHP overhead resources in speed and memory usage to optimize storage of the file data; whereas MS Excel will reduce filesize requirements by optimizing storage. Building a native Excel format file in PHP is slow and memory hungry already

As an example of this, all string data is maintained in a shared strings table. When two or more cells contain the same string value, MS Excel will point them both to the same entry in the shared strings table, so that the string data is only stored once. PHPExcel doesn't do this check to see if a string value is already in the shared strings table, but simply creates a new entry, so the string is stored twice. This reduces time taken to save the data by eliminating the overhead of checking is the string already in the table, but at a cost in duplication and hence in filesize.

The key question is "which is more important? To be able to read/edit/write native Excel files in PHP? To keep PHPExcel as fast and low-memory as possible?
 Or to have the smallest possible filesize on disk?"

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a way to mimic the effect of open/save in PHP?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of..... if I was to introduce it in PHPExcel, then it would be at a cost of slower speed and increased memory usage for the save.... that's already slow, and shared strings table is just one example of the optimisations that MS Excel uses

Comment: Is filesize really that critical to you?

Comment: I have an issue to import the file generated in PHPExcel to a System. but The system accept the file after I open/save. the only difference that I could see was the size. I will investigate further and then post a new question.
Thank you

Comment: On the other hand, it should store only distinct strings. There are situations when not doing this will lead to errors.

Comment: Conversely, storing multiple pointers to a single string where a value is repeated can also lead to errors, especially when one of those cells is changed, and the pointer needs changing as well as (possibly) a new string value adding to the shared string table.... and that's more likely to lead to errors than storing each string independently, because it's a higher complexity action